# Better process for Content Porter deployments

Tags: sdl-tridion, content-porter

We are considering how we can get away from Content Porter packages for our future deployments as we move to more rapid CI/CD deployments.

We want to avoid managing our TBB assemblies, Workflow DLL as CP assets.

We would like to also be able to have things like Schemas stored as XML in our GIT repository and created/updated from that XML.

Having CP packages with multiple releases in-flight will not scale very well. I hope the question is clear... Happy to help clarify. Looking for your recommendations.

Comment: Just a comment that if you want SDL’s guidance you may be better off asking SDL. This site is community driven and SDL has no ownership of it. I don’t mean that you don’t get valid advice here, sometimes from people that work at SDL, but the way you phrased your question sounds like you’re searching for “official” advice.

Comment: Yes, posted to SDL support also... and removed that statement here in this post :)

Answer (score 1):

Just my thought and idea, I think OOTB - you could think of writing a PowerShell Automation script to import your packages using ImportService and then link that script to your CI/CD Deployments, It's still possible whatever we do in our content porting options you could able to achieve using core services.

One time any way you need to prepare that deployment package of your CM Side changes, prepare it using a content porter by exporting package and keep it part of your git repository then easy to roll out that same Content Porter package to multiple environments based on the environment using environment-specific core service

I hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

As Velu says, you can script the export and import of "content porter" packages via the Import/Export service API. Essentially, all the core functionality of Content Porter has gradually moved to the server, and the Content Porter client is just user interface. Things that were tricky using the client don't magically become easy with the service, but it can be automated.

On the plus side, much of the Content Porter's complexity is in dependency management. Traditional software releases using Content Porter usually involve switching off the dependency management and managing dependencies yourself. This is the area where you should be having a long hard think about what you are trying to do. Possible strategies include:

- Always export everything
- Ensure that any items you depend on are present in the same package
- Use multiple packages, ensuring that depended-on items are imported first

Dependency strategy is enough of a subject in itself that you could probably ask specific questions here about these issues when you run into them.

You don't have to use Content Porter or the Import/Export API. TBBs etc, are either text items or binary items, and you can create and update these using the standard core service or webdav. This is likely only to be interesting for local edge cases, particularly as the Content Porter translates Tcm URIs backwards and forwards to WebDAVUrls as necessary, and while you could do that yourself it might feel like reinventing the wheel.

For some kinds of assets, such as Workflow, Events or any kind of extension that needs to be installed on the server, you could consider XCopy deployment or building Windows installers, the latter particularly if you want to do a GAC install. (Maybe these updates will be infrequent enough that it isn't a priority to make it part of your CI/CD setup.) You might also want to look at creating your own [Alchemy](https://www.alchemywebstore.com/) plugins.

This whole area is of huge interest right now, as many Tridion customers make the transition to more modern development practices. Your question, as it stands, isn't detailed enough to ask more than "is it possible". The answer is yes, but we're all busy trying to figure out exactly how. Each situation will be different, but our community can be hugely powerful in helping to coalesce around shared good practice. I hope you'll be asking more detailed and specific questions as you get deeper into it.